# Specify datetime2 format in Azure SQL data warehouse (synapse)

Tags: azure, data-warehouse, azure-synapse

What is the correct way to specify the format of a datetime2 field when creating a table in Azure SQL data warehouse? I don't seem to be able to find an example in the documentation.

The data looks like this:

"2020-09-14T20:50:48.000Z"

```
CREATE TABLE [Foo].[Bar](
    ...
    MyDateTime datetime2(['YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.fractional seconds]')
)
```

Comment: Dates have no formats, they are binary values, just like `int`, `decimal` or `varbinary`. No if or but. Formats apply only when a string is generated based from that binary value, or a string gets parsed into that binary value. Formatting is the job of the *client*, whether it's a web app or reporting engine. After all, only the client knows the end user's locale and regional settings

Comment: BTW that applies to *all* database products, not just SQL Server. That's what allows databases to serve clients on any locale, any format. If you stored a date *string* with a localized format you wouldn't be able to read it without using the exact same format (never mind taking extra space). Worse, there would be no way to check for incorrect parsing - what is `4/7`? July 4 or April 7?

Answer (score 0):

As Panagiotis notes, the underlying representation is an int/long for the actual date value. This is how RDBMS engines can quickly compute the delta between two dates (days between Monday and Friday is a simple subtraction problem). To answer your question, you simply would format your create table as:

```
CREATE TABLE [Foo].[Bar](
    ...
    MyDateTime datetime2
)
```

If you're interested in formatting the result in a query, you can look to the [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) or [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) functions. For example, if you wanted the format *dd-mm-yyyy* (Italian date), you could use either of the following:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 105)
    , FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'dd-MM-yyyy')
```

Note: *CONVERT* is generally faster than *FORMAT* and is the recommended approach if you have a date format that is supported. This is because the *FORMAT* function relies on the CLR which will include a context/process jump.